# Delete a zone from named.conf with shell script

Tags: centos, bind, shell-scripting

I am trying to delete an existing zone record from bind's named.conf file (on a centos 7 release).

The zone record looks like that:

```
zone "example.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "example.com.zone";
};
```

The command:

```
sed -nie '/\"example.com\"/,/^\};$/d;p;' /etc/named.conf
```

deletes that record (as supposed to).

Next, I have created the following shell script (rm-zone.sh) with executable permissions to do the same job:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ $# -lt 1 ] && {
        echo "usage: $0 <domain>"
        exit 1
}

domain=$1

sed -nie '/\"$domain\"/,/^\};$/d;p;' /etc/named.conf

rndc reload

echo Zone: $domain deleted successfully
```

When I log in as root and run the command:

```
./rm-zone.sh example.com
```

I see the message "Zone example.com deleted successfully" but the zone is still in my named.conf file...

Again, when I give the above mentioned command from cli:

```
sed -nie '/\"example.com\"/,/^\};$/d;p;' /etc/named.conf
```

the zone is properly deleted!!!

Apparently there is something wrong in the shell script, but haven't managed to find out what it is...

Any ideas as to what I'm missing here will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
sed -nie "/\"$domain\"/,/^\};"'$/d;p;' /etc/named.conf
```

instead of

```
sed -nie '/\"$domain\"/,/^\};$/d;p;' /etc/named.conf
```

The single quotes disable the shell's interpretation of either `\|` or `$domain`.

Comment: That didn't work either... it just needed a couple more single quotes around the $domain, and worked like charm:
sed -nie '/\"'$domain'\"/,/^\};$/d;p;' /etc/named.conf

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the actual problem you are solving, I think it'd probably be worth looking into using [`rndc addzone`/`rndc delzone`](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.11/doc/arm/man.rndc.html) (reliant on the [`allow-new-zones`](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.11/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#boolean_options) option) to allow automation of adding/deleting zones rather than scripting modification of `named.conf` yourself.

While I'm not sure what exactly goes wrong in your script, the way it is written it will just steamroll through and unconditionally print the "deleted successfully" message at the end, no matter what happens.

Maybe adding `set -ex` early in the script would help for troubleshooting? (And the `-e` may be a good idea in general?)

It may also be prudent to keep some kind of backup that you can revert to in case of failure, and maybe invoking `named-checkconf` to check that the new file seems somewhat sane?